# Authorization between services Django and NodeJs

Tags: node.js, django, microservices

I'm building an app using `React` on the frontend and `Django` and `Nodejs` on the backend. On the Django side I store the users and user authorization.

Right now I'm using `django-rest-knox` to generate the user token, but the problem is that if I make a request to Nodejs service I cannot decrypt the token there. I must to make another request to Django service to verify the token.

A solution would be to use `JWT Token`. But the JWT Token is not  stored to database ( I cannot change the expiration type per individual token)

I somebody here that faced the same problem like me or can give me an advice ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know you have two options :
The first consists of Django API acting like an authentification gateway, meaning that you have to pass by Django. (JWT)

The second solution is to use the digital signature (public/private key asymmetric mechanism) (JWT)[public key and private key in digital signatures](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/json-web-tokens-with-public-key-signatures)